# Jquery or CSS?...For Zooming div

Tags: jquery, css

```
<html>
  <body>
     <div id="text">
        <marquee>
            Hello there.....
        </marquee>
     </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to make a "Magnifying glass" effect to the `<div>`, but only in the middle of it (not the whole div).

Is there any solution for this in CSS or Jquery?

Comment: Could you provide more information? can't picture it..

Comment: Of course,Mel...I have a <div>,with a text running in it (marquee). Now what I'm trying to do is zoom effect on some part of the <div> and not the whole <div>...

Comment: Read this useful article : http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2010/05/25-excellent-jquery-image-zoom-plugins-creating-stunning-image-effects.html

Comment: Hi @BorisD you should avoid using the marquee tag as it's non-conformant element and posses accessibility issues (http://www.w3.org/WAI/GL/WCAG20/tests/test69.html) if you *really* need to provide scrolling text it can be found in the CSS2 spec and provide an accessible alternative version.

Comment: HI diEcho...I saw all this jquery plugins...the main problem with all those example is that...in my case I need the zoom to be static...not with a mouse hover or whatever....static <div> with static zoom...without any dependence of a mouse

Comment: Alex Key...as I was looking for alternative for HTML marquee, the only thing that I found is a Jquery solutions...some of them plugins and some of them using marquee as well...Is there anyway to do it in CSS?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at this links: http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2010/05/25-excellent-jquery-image-zoom-plugins-creating-stunning-image-effects.html

It has many different solutions, maybe on of them will fit your needs.

This, for example:

[image]

Or this:

[image]

Comment: Very nice effects, but the OP wants to zoom a text element and not an image, so would this technique work for arbitrary HTML elements or just images? I'm not sure...